# How to loop over files, then match partial string and get the respective values R

Tags: r

This must be very simple, but I am really confused with this. I have many files in `/mydir`. For example-

Files in `list.files("/mydir")`:

```
myfiles <- c("new_Ago2_1_LTR_assembly.csv", "new_Ago2_2_LTR_assembly.csv", 
"new_DCLd_1_LTR_assembly.csv", "new_DCLd_2_LTR_assembly.csv", "not_wanted_files")
```

All of these files are in this format:

```
  length      A      C      G      T
1     18   1890   3328   1646   3067
2     19   4444   8221   4914   8668
3     20  12090  18073  12903  19726
4     21  38719  35510  30843  41125
```

I want to loop over all files in `myfiles` and by doing the partial match with the file names with the list (Ago2_1,Ago2_2,DCLd_1,DCLd_2) below, I want to put there respective values in `getvalue` below in the code for the division of the dataframe.

```
Ago2_1  <-  29,911,751
Ago2_2  <-  29,564,885
DCLd_1  <-  67,004,254
DCLd_2  <-  77,682,528

getvalue <-      #this is where I am confused- how can I do the partial match with the file name and put the respective value?!!
```

Here is the code:

```
  for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){


      df<- read.table("myfiles[i]", header= TRUE)

      df<- df[,c("length","A","C","G","T")]


      test<- cbind(df$length,(df[,c("A","T","G","C")]/(getvalue [????Need help Here!])))
   ##Additional  FUNCTION . to be executed!!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create named vector, then use grep to get index using grepl:

```
# lookup values 
myValues <- setNames(c(29911751, 29564885, 67004254, 77682528), 
                     c("Ago2_1","Ago2_2","DCLd_1","DCLd_2"))

# For loop start
# testing
# i = myfiles[1]

# get value
ix <- which(sapply(names(myValues), function(j)grepl(j, i)))
getvalue <- myValues[ ix ]

# For loop end
```